# Adding masterpage to aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am currently referencing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstorole.aspx) website for AD role management.

The C# code is working fine, but when I pasted the code inside my webpage along with the masterpage, the page gave me an error which says:

`Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.`

May I know how should I set my masterpage in this case?

.ASPX page without masterpage:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

  string[] rolesArray;
  MembershipUserCollection users;
  string[] usersInRole;

  public void Page_Load()
  {
  ....
  }


  public void AddUsers_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    ....
  }

  public void UsersInRoleGrid_RemoveFromRole(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs args)
  {
  ....
  }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
  <title>Sample: Role Membership</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form runat="server" id="PageForm">
    <font face="helvetica" size="6" color="#455c75"><strong>Role Membership</strong></font><font face="helvetica" size="5" color="#455c75"><strong> Management</strong></font>
    <br /><asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="maroon" runat="server" /><br />
    <table cellpadding="3" border="0">
      ...
    </table>
  </form>
```

Masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainPage.master.cs" Inherits="MainPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>SOD</title>
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried inserting `MasterPageFile="~/MainPage.master"` into the first tag, which start my .aspx page with `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainPage.master"%>`, giving me the error mentioned above.

Comment: Please post the markup of both - .master and .aspx page.

Comment: Your post isn't clear to me. Please say in a single line "what you want to do?" If you want to configure master page programatically then read these links : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-vb and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: i wish to set my .aspx webpage to format according to my masterpage , it is currently not using any masterpage

Comment: Then you have to edit your .aspx page at design time and add <asp:Content/> controls in it according to the master page design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Masterpage contains HTML code and content areas.  The pages that use the masterpage must, MUST, have all code in an <asp:Content> tag.  You can't have any sort of code outside of the Content tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your code inside an `<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content_pageBody" Runat="Server"></content>` tag. This tag should map to your master page, where ContentPlaceHolderID = the place holder name in your master page

Comment: The asp tag basically links to your master page saying the content in this tag goes into the spot in the master page that I link to. If you create a new page, and select "use a master page". Then select your master page, you will see the scaffolding code that shows you the asp content tags you need.